# How do i change, div of image to change colour when hover in CSS

Tags: css

Here is my css  i would like to add another png pic which is with inverted color when hovered. how can i do it ?

```
div#artlog{
width:910px;
height: 58px;
margin-top: 20px;
background-image: url("../obr/artisthead.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add a hover class

```
div#artlog:hover{
       background-image: url("../obr/artisthead-inverted.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, I think it would resolve your problem:

```
div#artlog:hover{
width:910px;
height: 58px;
margin-top: 20px;
background-image: url("../obr/inverted_color_artisthead.jpg");
```

Don't forget to place `inverted_color_artisthead.jpg` in the same folder as the other image.
For more details you can read [w3.org documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)